# App crashes when not connected to mac, runs fine through Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

For some reason my app crashes when I run it without Xcode. When it is run through Xcode, there are no problems AT ALL. I have no idea why this is happening.

Has anyone has this happen to them?

Thanks

Comment: Its really difficult to tell exact answer to the problem. I would suggest put some breakpoints to methods(viewDidLoad & so on) & check if app works properly. Delete the app from iPhone/simulator. Switch OFF your iPhone.  ON it again & then run.

Comment: You can get crash logs from the device when you reconnect it, use the console in the Xcode organiser. Without that, there's not much anyone can help with.

Comment: @jrturton How do you get crash logs?

Comment: Plug the phone back in, Xcode --> organiser --> devices --> your device --> device logs

Comment: @jrturton What do I do when I have the crash report?

Comment: Read it ;). Add it to your question if you don't understand it.

Comment: No idea why this is being downvoted. I'm having exactly the same issue. My app works perfectly while plugged in and fails to launch when I try it on the iPad alone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read crash report first.

Synchronize device with iTunes, crash reports are copied from the device onto the system running iTunes

The location of the report is dependent on the OS:

Mac OS X: ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/

Comment: What do I do when I have the crash report?

Comment: Use iTunes sync summary of your device. Then go to ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/ to find the crash report

Comment: Sync Summary of your device use itunes.

Answer (score 0):

If your app crashes on start, you should check your code to see you dont use methods or libraries that aren't supported in your iOS.